# Duplicate image in a folder logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to find the count of duplicate images in a folder.  I want to print unique image with the count(how many duplicates does it have). How can I do it?
My Present code:

```
for i in image_path_list:
image2 = cv2.imread(i)
image2 = cv2.resize(image2,(360,480))
for j in image_path_list:
    if i!=j:
        image1=cv2.imread(j)
        image1=cv2.resize(image1, (360,480))
        difference = cv2.subtract(image1, image2)

        result = not np.any(difference) #if difference is all zeros it will return False

        if result is True:

            print(i)
        else:

            continue
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation - it matters in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an HASH, to check wheter the file is already in that directory.

Generate an Hash for each file, write it to an Array / Database and check if the hash for each file is already in that directory - if so delete it / count += 1.

Also:

```
https://github.com/philipbl/duplicate-images
```

Comment: I dont want to use HASH. Please help me to solve with my above logic